# How do I make os.system not kill the script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I've got this line in my python script:

```
os.system("feh ./img/ && rm -rf ./img/")

print("This won't print")
```

But when it executes, it stops the entire rest of the script from running, so it will execute "feh ./img/ && rm -rf ./img/", but the last print statement doesn't print.

How do I run it without killing the rest of the script?

Comment: weird it works for me

Comment: If nobody but you has the problem, how would anyone but you be helped by a "solution" (or even be able to understand in what circumstances they might encounter the same issue themselves)? We really need a [mre] others can follow to see the same issue before this can be a suitable Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

Just run it with subprocess.call([args])

For examples, this program could be achieved with

```
subprocess.call(["feh", "./img/"])
shutil.rmtree("./img/")
```

Comment: It's not clear this *solved* the original problem, as `os.system` should not have killed your script in the first place. But the `subprocess` module is indeed preferred over using `os.system`.